# Distribution of product of bernoulli random variable and poisson random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are random variable $Z=XY$ ($X$ is poisson and $Y$ is bernoulli)

$$X(n;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$

$$Y=\begin{cases} & \beta \text{ with probability } \beta \\  & 0 \text{ probability } 1-\beta \end{cases}$$

I likes to know distribution of product of bernoulli random variable and poisson random variable.

So i calculate MGF(Moment Generating Function) so i can get below expression.

$$M_{z}(t)=\sum_{y}\sum_{x}e^{txy}P(x)P(y)=\sum_{x}(\beta e^{t\beta x}+1-\beta) P(x) 
=\beta e^{-\lambda}(e^{\lambda e^{t\beta}})+1-\beta = \beta(e^{\lambda(e^{t\beta -1})}+1-\beta)$$

I can`t obtain pmf(probability mass function) from this calcultaed MGF

Is it impossible obtain pmf ?

Or is there any technique obtaining probability in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can think about it for a bit. Presumably theres a typo in $Y$, which should be 1 w.p. $\beta$.

Note that $Z$ is zero iff $Y=0$ or $X=0$ (which are independent events), so $P(Z=0) = P(Y=0) + P(X=0) - P(X=0)P(Y=0)$.

Note that $Z=z$ where $z$ is a positive integer if and only if $Y=1$ and $X=z$ (which are independent events), so $P(Z=z) = P(Y=1) P(X=z)$.

Comment: Oops, thanks. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Expected value of a die-roll is $3.5$. If you have a coin with both sides marked $3.5$, the expected value of that coin toss is $3.5$. But these two experiments have different probability distribution associated with them. So you can't in general hope to extract pmf from expected value.

$$
P(Z=n\beta)={\lambda}^n{e^{-\lambda}\over n!}\beta\;\forall\;n>0\\
P(Z=0)=e^{-\lambda}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\lambda}^n{e^{-\lambda}\over n!}(1-\beta)\\
=e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})(1-\beta)=1-\beta+e^{-\lambda}\beta
$$
These exhaust all possible values of $Z$. It's easy to see these probabilities sum to $1$ as they should.